# 2D Interpolation with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, interpolation

I'm running a simulation on a 2D space with periodic boundary conditions.  A continuous function is represented by its values on a grid.  I need to be able to evaluate the function and its gradient at any point in the space.  Fundamentally, this isn't a hard problem -- or to be precise, it's an almost already solved problem.  The function can be interpolated using a cubic spline with scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline.  The reason it's *almost* solved is that RectBivariateSpline cannot handle periodic boundary conditions, nor can anything else in scipy.interpolate, as far as I can figure out from the documentation.

Is there a python package that can do this?  If not, can I adapt scipy.interpolate to handle periodic boundary conditions?  For instance, would it be enough to put a border of, say, four grid elements around the entire space and explicitly represent the periodic condition on it?

[ADDENDUM] A little more detail, in case it matters: I am simulating the motion of animals in a chemical gradient.  The continuous function I mentioned above is the concentration of a chemical that they are attracted to.  It changes with time and space according to a straightforward reaction/diffusion equation.  Each animal has an x,y position (which cannot be assumed to be at a grid point). They move up the gradient of attractant.  I'm using periodic boundary conditions as a simple way of imitating an unbounded space.

Comment: Splines are not by their nature periodic - can you not fit a set of sine/cosines instead?

Comment: Sure, I could do that, if I want to write my own interpolator from scratch.  But if I'm going to write my own from scratch, I can also write a spline interpolator that works with periodic boundaries.  It's not hard to see how to do that.  If I have to, I will.  But I'd MUCH rather use a well-designed, optimized and maintained package written by a pro.

Comment: You could create a 3x3 grid of replications, perform the interpolation over this expanded grid, and then only return the middle cell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that the python function that comes closest is scipy.signal.cspline2d. This is exactly what I want, *except* that it assumes mirror-symmetric boundary conditions. Thus, it appears that I have three options:

1. Write my own cubic spline interpolation function that works with periodic boundary conditions, perhaps using the cspline2d sources (which are based on functions written in C) as a starting point.
2. The kludge: the effect of data at i on the spline coefficient at j
   goes as r^|i-j|, with r = -2 + sqrt(3) ~ -0.26.  So the effect of
   the edge is down to r^20 ~ 10^-5 if I nest the grid within a border
   of width 20 all the way around that replicates the periodic values,
   something like this:

   bzs1 = np.array(
       [zs1[i%n,j%n] for i in range(-20, n+20) for j in range(-20, n+20)] )
   bzs1 = bzs1.reshape((n + 40, n + 40))

   Then I call cspline2d on the whole array, but use only the middle. This should work, but it's ugly.
3. Use Hermite interpolation instead. In a 2D regular grid, this corresponds to [bicubic interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation). The disadvantage is that the interpolated function has a discontinuous second derivative. The advantages are it is (1) relatively easy to code, and (2) for my application, computationally efficient. At the moment, this is the solution I'm favoring.

I did the math for interpolation with trig functions rather than polynomials, as @mdurant suggested. It turns out to be very similar to the cubic spline, but requires more computation and produces worse results, so I won't be doing that.

**EDIT:** A colleague told me of a fourth solution:

1. The [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) (GSL) has interpolation functions that can handle periodic boundary conditions.  There are two (at least) python interfaces to GSL: [PyGSL](http://pygsl.sourceforge.net/) and [CythonGSL](https://github.com/twiecki/CythonGSL). Unfortunately, GSL interpolation seems to be restricted to one dimension, so it's not a lot of use to me, but there's lots of good stuff in GSL.

Answer (score 1):

Another function that could work is `scipy.ndimage.interpolation.map_coordinates`.
It does spline interpolation with periodic boundary conditions.
It does not not directly provide derivatives, but you could calculate them numerically.

Comment: However, note that convention for periodic boundary conditions may not be what you expect: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49280404/shift-interpolation-does-not-give-expected-behaviour

Answer (score 0):

These functions can be found at my github, [`master/hmc/lattice.py`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/tree/master/hmc/lattice.py):

- **Periodic boundary conditions** The `Periodic_Lattice()` class is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38066786/4013571) in full.
- **Lattice Derivatives** In the repository you will find a laplacian function, a squared gradient (for the gradient just take the square root) and and overloaded version of `np.ndarray`
- **Unit Tests** The test cases can be found in same repo in [`tests/test_lattice.py`](https://github.com/flipdazed/Hybrid-Monte-Carlo/blob/master/test/test_lattice.py)

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the following function which augments the input to create data with effective periodic boundary conditions. Augmenting the data has a distinct advantage over modifying an existing algorithm: the augmented data can easily be interpolated using any algorithm. See below for an example.

```
def augment_with_periodic_bc(points, values, domain):
    """
    Augment the data to create periodic boundary conditions.

    Parameters
    ----------
    points : tuple of ndarray of float, with shapes (m1, ), ..., (mn, )
        The points defining the regular grid in n dimensions.
    values : array_like, shape (m1, ..., mn, ...)
        The data on the regular grid in n dimensions.
    domain : float or None or array_like of shape (n, )
        The size of the domain along each of the n dimenions
        or a uniform domain size along all dimensions if a 
        scalar. Using None specifies aperiodic boundary conditions.

    Returns
    -------
    points : tuple of ndarray of float, with shapes (m1, ), ..., (mn, )
        The points defining the regular grid in n dimensions with 
        periodic boundary conditions.
    values : array_like, shape (m1, ..., mn, ...)
        The data on the regular grid in n dimensions with periodic
        boundary conditions.
    """
    # Validate the domain argument
    n = len(points)
    if np.ndim(domain) == 0:
        domain = [domain] * n
    if np.shape(domain) != (n,):
        raise ValueError("`domain` must be a scalar or have the same "
                         "length as `points`")

    # Pre- and append repeated points
    points = [x if d is None else np.concatenate([x - d, x, x + d]) 
              for x, d in zip(points, domain)]

    # Tile the values as necessary
    reps = [1 if d is None else 3 for d in domain]
    values = np.tile(values, reps)

    return points, values
```

## Example

The example below shows interpolation with periodic boundary conditions in one dimension but the function above can be applied in arbitrary dimensions.

[image: example of periodic interpolation]

```
rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 144
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, True, True)

np.random.seed(0)
x = np.linspace(0, 1, 10, endpoint=False)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x)
ax = axes[0, 0]
ax.plot(x, y, marker='.')
ax.set_title('Points to interpolate')

sampled = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 100)
y_sampled = interpolate.interpn([x], y, sampled, bounds_error=False)
valid = ~np.isnan(y_sampled)
ax = axes[0, 1]
ax.scatter(sampled, np.where(valid, y_sampled, 0), marker='.', c=np.where(valid, 'C0', 'C1'))
ax.set_title('interpn w/o periodic bc')

[x], y = augment_with_periodic_bc([x], y, domain=1.0)
y_sampled_bc = interpolate.interpn([x], y, sampled)
ax = axes[1, 0]
ax.scatter(sampled, y_sampled_bc, marker='.')
ax.set_title('interpn w/ periodic bc')

y_sampled_bc_cubic = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, 'cubic')(sampled)
ax = axes[1, 1]
ax.scatter(sampled, y_sampled_bc_cubic, marker='.')
ax.set_title('cubic interp1d w/ periodic bc')

fig.tight_layout()
```

Comment: Hi, I hope that you are doing fine. I am currently facing the same problem. How to make the values f[0]=f[2pi]. This can be done, but the derivative is clearly discontinuous.  Is your function able to make the derivative continuous?